# Having a trouble in making a text-based RPG (text area/field related)

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a simple, text-based RPG but got stuck at the very beginning.

I've learned Java for about a month now and somehow could succeed to make a simple text-adventure game(by using Scanner, println, if-statement etc) that works on CMD.

So I decided to make a little more advanced one(hopefully Wizardry-like stuff) that can be played on a window.

So far I've learned how to make a window with frame and put some panels, text areas etc. But now I'm hitting a wall.

What I'm trying to do (but unable to do) is:

1. Enter a number in a text field as a player command and display another text on a text area according to the number that was entered.
2. Clear the text that is already displayed in the text area.

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JFrame window;
JPanel p1;
JPanel p2;
JPanel p3;
JPanel p4;
JPanel p5;  
JButton graphic;
JTextArea statusT;
JTextArea storyT;
JTextField input;
JButton commandB1;
JButton commandB2;
JButton commandB3;
JButton commandB4;
JButton commandB5;

public static void main(String[]args)
{       

    Main game = new Main();
    game.opening();

}

public void opening()
{

    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setBounds(200,200,1024,768);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBackground(Color.black);
    window.setLayout(null); //Disabling the default layout.

    Font basicfont = new Font("MS Gothic", Font.PLAIN, 20);

    // Panel Setup          
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(); //This is where graphics are displayed.
    p1.setBounds(10, 10, 650, 350); //Panel layout(x,y,x,y)
    p1.setBackground(Color.black);

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel(); //This is where status is displayed.
    p2.setBounds(670, 10, 325, 350);
    p2.setBackground(Color.black);      

    JPanel p3 = new JPanel(); //This is where story text is displayed.
    p3.setBounds(10, 370, 650, 350);
    p3.setBackground(Color.black);

    JPanel p4 = new JPanel(); //This is where command menu is displayed.
    p4.setBounds(670, 370, 325, 300);
    p4.setBackground(Color.black);
    p4.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1)); //Setting the layout of Panel 4

    JPanel p5 = new JPanel(); //This is the text-entry box.
    p5.setBounds(670, 680, 325, 50);

    // TextArea Setup       
    JTextArea statusT = new JTextArea();
    JTextArea storyT = new JTextArea();     
    JTextField input = new JTextField(32);


    JButton commandB1 = new JButton("1:Stay");
    JButton commandB2 = new JButton("2:Attack the man");
    JButton commandB3 = new JButton("3:Drink");
    JButton commandB4 = new JButton("4:Leave");
    JButton commandB5 = new JButton("5:(Debug)Clear the text");

    //Graphic setup
    //graphic = new JButton(new ImageIcon("dungeonSample.jpg"));
    //graphic.setBackground(Color.black);


    //Status text setup                     
    statusT.setFont(basicfont);
    statusT.setBackground(Color.black);
    statusT.setForeground(Color.white);
    statusT.setText("\nLV     6\nHP   100\nMP    28\nG    120\nEXP   36"); //Ths is just a sample status

    //Story text setup
    storyT.setFont(basicfont);
    storyT.setBackground(Color.black);
    storyT.setForeground(Color.white);
    storyT.setText("<The innkeeper>\nHello this is an adventurer's inn. 8 golds for a night. \nWhat do you want to do?");

    //Input box setup
    input.setFont(basicfont);
    input.setBackground(Color.black);
    input.setForeground(Color.white);
    //input.setText("Input a number here>");        
    input.addActionListener(this);



    // Add Text>>Panel>>Window
    //p1.add(graphic);
    p2.add(statusT);
    p3.add(storyT);
    p4.add(commandB1);
    p4.add(commandB2);
    p4.add(commandB3);
    p4.add(commandB4);
    p4.add(commandB5);
    p5.add(input);

    window.add(p1);
    window.add(p2);
    window.add(p3);
    window.add(p4);
    window.add(p5);

    window.setVisible(true);            
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

    String choice = input.getText();

    if(choice.equals("1")){
        storyT.setText("All right, sleep well.");
    }
    if(choice.equals("2"))
    {
        storyT.setText("What, you think you can rob me?!\n\nThe inkeeper attacked!\n6870 points of damage!\nYou are dead.");
    }
    if(choice.equals("3"))
    {
        storyT.setText("Sorry, we can't serve booze anymore because of the restriction by the lord");
    }
    if(choice.equals("4"))
    {
        storyT.setText("See ya.");          
    }
    if(choice.equals("5"))
    {
        storyT.setText("");         
    }

}


}
```

In this sample situation, I was hoping if you enter "1" in the input box(the text field on panel p5), the innkeeper's default dialogue ("Hello this is an adventurer's inn....") will be replaced with the string "All right, sleep well." But even if I enter "1"(or any other number) nothing changes and an error message is displayed on the console.

I also tried to clear the default text by entering "5" in the text field but that also doesn't work.

I know I did something wrong somewhere but I don't know where it is. I tried to find a solution on the internet but haven't found any effective info yet.

I will be very grateful if someone could tell me what I should do.

Comment: Try this. Type '1' in the input text field and press the 'Enter' key

Comment: *"I will be very grateful if someone could tell me what I should do."*  When posting to a Q&A site, asking a question would be a good start..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
JTextArea statusT = new JTextArea();
JTextArea storyT = new JTextArea();
JTextField input = new JTextField(32);
```

to this

```
 statusT = new JTextArea();
 storyT = new JTextArea();
 input = new JTextField(32);
```

you are not initializing textareas that you have created as instance .you are creating new textareas.so instance textareas are null.that's why you are getting null pointer exception

```
  JTextArea statusT;
  JTextArea storyT;
  JTextField input;
```

these three aren't initiated yet.don't create another `statusT,storyT,input` as local .

Comment: Ryi: look up "variable shadowing". 1+

Comment: >Fast Snail  It worked! Thank you so much! It seems it was a very simple mistake...I think I have to learn more about the definition of initializing. Thanks again!